# get regional setting from android

Tags: android

How can I get the `regional setting` of user's mobile in android?
As I can't find related information how to get it in android.

eg. if his current setting is in Singapore, will get Singapore.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the Locale class for localization / regional information :

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html

Ex. Locale defaultLocale = Locale.getDefault();

Read the section labeled "Be wary of the default locale" which can save you from some issues with getDefault() from the Locale class when used for more than just user presentation.

Answer (score 1):

This might help

```
Context c = getBaseContext();
Resources r = c.getResources();  
Configuration config = r.getConfiguration();   
Locale currentLocale = config.locale;
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way from an Activity is:

```
Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
Log.d("TAG", "Country: " + l.getDisplayCountry());
```